# How can you perform a git revert AND remove the merge history?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-revert

This question is in relation to [How can you tell who merged which branch into git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910224/how-can-you-tell-who-merged-which-branch-into-git).

Basically, `develop` was accidentally merged into `master` *before* we were ready, causing `master` to be unstable. `master` was then `push`ed/`pull`ed to various machines. In an attempt to resolve the issue, I performed a `git revert` to undo the changes without understanding all the implications of the command: that the **data** changes would be undone, but the **history** would not. I.e., `master`'s previous commits includes that of `develop`, meaning that in the future when we *are* ready to merge `develop` into `master`, any valid commits on `develop` before issuing `git revert` will not be included in the merge.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you can't (revert and at the same time "undo" the history).

What you *can* do, though, is repeat the merge on a new, different, temporary branch (such as an anonymous branch) on which the faulty merge has never occurred.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28191593/1256452) for methods.  You can then use the resulting tree to make a "corrected merge" commit on the target branch (`master`, in this case).  This "corrected merge" commit will not, itself, be a merge commit, just an ordinary commit, but it will have the *contents* that you want.

If you want to retain the extra "re-merge history" you can make this a real merge of or on the temporary anonymous branch.  That's just a matter of supplying the desired parent-commit IDs, whether by doing a real merge into `master`, faking up a `MERGE_HEAD` file, doing an `--ours` merge into the anonymous branch and then swapping the labels around, or supplying the right parents to `git commit-tree`.  (The exact details depend on how you want any `--first-parent` revision tracking to go.)

Note that if needed, you can cherry-pick additional commits into the anonymous branch before using it for the tree.  Or, if you elect the "real merge" method, you can just merge the temporary branch result into `master`:

```
... - o - m - w - A - B - *    <-- master
        \/               /
        /\_____ M ______/      <-- temp-branch
       /       /
... - o - o - o                <-- develop
```

Here all the `o`s are boring ordinary commits, `m` is the bad merge, `w` is its reversion, and `A` and `B` are commits on master that you wish to preserve (they're shown as non-merge commits but they can be merges: the important part here is their attached trees).  Then, `M` is the re-done, correct merge on the temporary branch, and `*` is the final merge back into `master`, after which you can delete the `temp-branch` label while retaining the underlying branch in the commit graph.  In this particular scenario you'd use these commands (though I omit any merge conflict resolution required):

```
$ git checkout -b temp-branch <master-commit-before-m>
$ git merge develop
$ git checkout master
$ git merge temp-branch  # be sure to fix up the merge message
$ git branch -d temp-branch
```

and the first parent of commit `*` is then `B`, with its second parent being commit `M`.

The trick here is remembering that you need to do this, and finding the correct commit on `master` (the one that was the tip of branch `master` just before the faulty merge; it's the first parent of faulty merge `m`, and you can give it a tag now, or even give it a branch name now, while you know where it is, rather than using `git checkout -b temp-branch <sha1>` later after having to re-locate the SHA-1—but if you do this, pick a name that's more meaningful than `temp-branch`!).

The "remembering that you need to do this" is really the hardest part.  All the rest is mere fussing-about with git.